# Are nameservers with heterogeneous TLDs acceptable in DNS records?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy, amazon-route53

I am trying to migrate my nameservers from GoDaddy to Amazon Route 53. I would like to edit my DNS record to first add the Amazon Route 53 servers, let that propagate, then remove the GoDaddy servers.

Is it acceptable for my DNS record to have multiple nameservers on different hosts with different top-level domains, provided they all return identical Zone files (ie they all return the same A, CNAME and MX records)? GoDaddy said it could break things, but couldn't explain how.

Thanks,

-Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want the servers to present the same SOA information, too - particularly, the zone serial number.  This may not be possible, as it's unlikely that you're able to control this with these providers.

It's not really buying you anything to have it split like that, though - might as well just change over all at once.

Set up all the records on the Amazon servers, then switch the domain to point to them.  It will take some time for clients to switch completely off of the GoDaddy servers, but regardless of whether a resolver has cached the old GoDaddy delegation, or switches to the new Amazon delegation, they'll have working name resolution - and you won't be presenting potentially conflicting information from two different SOA records.

Comment: Thanks for this info! The risk (I think) is that GoDaddy will delete my zone record when it detects I'm trying to move off. That is what just happened to us on Monday. It may be intentional as a way to punish customers who are attempting to leave by causing downtime...?

Comment: @esilver Well, as a paying customer, I'd recommend getting the lawyers involved if that happens - I wouldn't expect intentional malice like that, but maybe schedule the move in the middle of the night, just to be sure.